# How to do update in listing for web by using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating admin panel in website and I am using firebase as a database in backend.I am able to display listing but when I click on the particular listing there status should change from 'pending' to 'accept' but it doesnt.I dont know where I did mistake.Please give suggestion and I attach js file and database screenshot

pl.js

```
 var firebaseheadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("user");


    firebaseheadingRef.on('child_added',datasnapshot=>{

       var title= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("title").val();
       var userid= datasnapshot.child("username").val();
       var type= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("title").val();
       var publisheddate= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("publish").val();
       var expirydate= datasnapshot.child("listing").child("expire").val();

       $("#tablebody").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+userid+"</td><td>"+type+"</td><td>"+publisheddate+"</td><td><button type=button id=accept onclick=accept()>Accept</button><button type=button>Reject</button></td></tr>");
      });


    function accept()
    {
      firebaseheadingRef.on('child_changed',datasnapshot=>{
        datasnapshot.child("listing").child("status").update({"status":"accept"});
        setCommentValues(postElement, data.key, data.val().text, data.val().author);

      });
    }
```

database

[image]

listing display picture where I click on accept button then update of status should done

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where you need to change your code:

First, in the code that generates the table, you have to pass the id of the node to the function call, as follows. You get the node id with the [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) property of the `DataSnapshot`.

```
.....
$("#tablebody").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+userid+"</td><td>"+type+"</td><td>"+publisheddate+"</td><td><button type=button id=accept onclick=accept('" + datasnapshot.key + "')>Accept</button><button type=button>Reject</button></td></tr>");
...
```

And secondly you have to write your `accept()` function in such a way it updates the database value, with the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method. Like the following

```
function accept(userId) {
  var nodeRef = firebase.database().ref("/user/" + userId + "/listing/status");
  return nodeRef.set('accept');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and can you tell me how to do insert data and delete data on list on same database please?I am new to this

Comment: Here is the doc for inserting and deleting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data